# How to find the highest value of the each row with number of columns and print them?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, dataframe

I have a csv file that has over 1000 rows and 50 columns. Each row has values (i.e. 0.554562) and each column has the same type of values:

As an example of my csv file ():

```
       Albany  Ukraine  Germany  Swiss   England

kevin  0.5655  0.5777   0.3232   0.1212  0.9595

brayan 0.4655  0.2777   0.1232,  0.9212  0.5595

alex   0.1655  0.2777   0.3232   0.1212  0.9795
```

Now I want to find the highest values in each row and create new column and added there like:

```
        Albany Ukraine Germany Swiss  England highest

kevin   0.5655 0.5777  0.3232  0.1212 0.9595  0.9595

brayan  0.4655 0.2777  0.1232  0.9212 0.5595  0.9212

alex    0.1655 0.2777  0.3232  0.1212 0.9795  0.9795
```

I already checked a few posts here such as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743512/finding-the-sum-of-each-column-and-combined-them-to-find-the-top-3-highest-value) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990566/numpy-python-find-the-highest-value-from-a-column-for-each-unique-value-in-anot), but none of them helped me.

It would be great if you can provide your help with code that I can run in my side and learn. Thanks

Addition: Also is there any way to say like Kevin with the highest prob of [0.9595] is belong to England?

Comment: did you check with max ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300989/get-max-value-from-row-of-a-dataframe-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Work on `axis=1` (rows) and assign a new column using `max`

```
df["highest"] = df.max(axis=1)
```

Using `idxmax` will tell you *where* the max lies

```
top_prob = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you for your good comment. I am now able to get the highest value found and printed in a new column, but for the second part that you mentioned to use `top_prob = df.idxmax(axis=1)`, in my case where in my first column is the name of the country (and the column head is unnamed), it is preventing the process and i am getting error as: `TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype` do you have any suggestion to fix this. thank you